# Syntax error preventing CREATE EVENT

Tags: mysql, database, delimiter, mysql-error-1064, ddl

```
CREATE EVENT demo
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 2 SECOND
    DO BEGIN

      update alarm set is_on=1;

    END
```

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE EVENT demo
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 2 SECOND
    DO
      BEGIN
      update alarm set is_on=1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter when you run DDL statements like this. MySQL is interpreting your semicolon as the end of your `CREATE EVENT` query, not as a delimiter within it.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT demo
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 2 SECOND
    DO BEGIN

      update alarm set is_on=1;

    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```